# How to prove that my neural network satisfies convergence assumptions of the Adam optimizer?

Tags: neural-networks, adam

Recently, I read a paper ([this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.13290.pdf)) that provides convergence analysis of the Adam optimizer without assuming the smoothness condition of the loss function. Suppose I have a neural network $f(\theta)$ with a loss function $L$, and I want to verify if my network satisfy the assumptions (S1)-(S3) and (A1)-(A2). I am confused about how to prove that a specific network $f(\theta)$ and a specific loss function $L$ satisfies those assumptions. How should I get started?

Also, do these assumptions depend on the network architecture?

Note: Maybe this question seems a bit silly because I'm still relatively new to neural network analysis.